Sheet Presentation Sync Issue when Switching Tabs
In my app, I have a tabView which contains two tabs presenting the same view. The content in each view is dictated within the respective view. The views have a .sheet modifier which currently triggers based on an @Published var showSheet defined in an ObservableObject class.
The issue I see is occurring when I:

Navigate to one of the mentioned Tabs
Tap a button in the selected Tab's View which triggers the .sheet
Close the sheet
Navigate to the second mentioned Tab which presents the same view (different data)
Tap a button which triggers the .sheet

After tapping the button, the sheet pops but then is immediately dismissed without user interaction.
The goal is have the sheets open and close normally whilst being able to switch tabs normally as well.
It appears to me that triggerSheet is being upon arrival to the new tab but I cannot figure out why. I was able to reproduce the issue with something similar to the code below, hopefully the idea of what I am trying to accomplish is clear.
Code:
TabView:
struct TabView: View {
    @StateObject private var obsPresentation = ObsPresentation.shared
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    TabView(selection: $obsPresentation.currentTab) {
                            if obsPresentation.conditionOne {
                                HealthView()
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Label("Person 1 Health", systemImage: "heart")
                                    }
                                    .tag(obsPresentation.Tab.health1)
                            }
                            
                            if obsPresentation.conditionTwo {
                                HealthView()
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Label("Person 2 Health", systemImage: "heart")
                                    }
                                    .tag(obsPresentation.Tab.health2)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

HealthView:
struct HealthView: View {
    @StateObject private var obsPresentation = ObsPresentation.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid() {
                    ForEach(...) { _ in
                        Button(action: {
                            obsPresentation.showSheet()
                        }) {
                            ... UI
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $obsPresentation.triggerSheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

ObservedObject Class:
public class ObsPresentation: ObservableObject {
    public static var shared = ObsPresentation()
    
    public enum Tab {
        case health1, health2
    }
    
    @Published public var currentTab: Tab = .health1 {
        didSet {
            switch tabSelection {
            case .health1:
                ...
            case .health2:
                ...
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
    
// These conditions are manipulated elsewhere
    @Published public var condition1 = true 
    @Published public var condition2 = true
    
    @Published var triggerSheet = false

    func showSheet() {
        triggerSheet = true
    }
}

The obvious answer here would be to localize the binding sheetTrigger bool to HealthView() as an @State var which works for sheet presentation. However, my app also supports deep linking and some particular links need to navigate to a tab and open the sheet all at once. Therefore, the sheetTrigger bool must be accessible outside of the View so it can be toggled via the deep linking logic.
I have also tried creating a separate ObservableObject class, in a similar way as ObsPresentation, that just handles sheet based code. This caused the same behavior.
Thank you

You are not using ObservableObject the correct way to manage your model data.
See Managing model data ios16+ for how to use ObservableObject. See also Managing model data ios17+.
In other words, use only one source of truth @StateObject private var obsPresentation ... and pass it to other views. Also properties such as triggerSheet
do not belong in the model data, this is for Views to manage.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for the comment. I will look into using ObservableObject in the ways presented in the articles. Yes, I realize triggerSheet should be initialized in the View. I had trouble accessing via the deep link class which is why I had it in the ObservableObject here. I was able to solve this by passing a binding in to the View to help control the binding.

The primary issue is that you're using a shared state object which is set to true and never set to false based on the code you've provided. That means when you first present the sheet, it acts in a way that you're expecting, however the second time you present the sheet, it's only presented briefly then dismissed because you've effectively toggled the boolean to false on that second button. It looks like this, by execution order; Initialized false -> Button Tap -> Set true -> Sheet Presented -> Sheet Dismissed -> Second Button Tap -> Set false -> Weird behavior.
I also noticed you're using $obsPresentation.triggerSheet instead of obsPresentation.$triggerSheet which could also cause the problem, but I recommend below, a better solution regardless. I don't have my IDE right now, so I can't confirm that gut instinct. Basically you're telling it, "Hey update the view when the obsPresentation is updated!" instead of "Hey update the view when the property of triggerSheet ON obsPresentation is updated!"
So, if you've read this far, then surely, you're wondering, why is the sheet even presenting at all, given that it's set to false. That's because sheets have a unique behavior where they ignore certain thread actions while they're mid-animation. Your implementation is triggering the sheet to appear, because the @State is being updated, and in the context of the ViewBuilder it doesn't care if its true or false, simply that it's updated, and it should re-draw. However, while it's in the middle of that re-draw, it's published value flips to false, thus causing the sheet to disappear. Similar weird behavior can happen by dismissing a parent of the sheet, from the parent, while a sheet is presented as proof of this. So how do you fix it?
The best way to fix a sheet, in particular one that you're using for different things, is to use an Enum in place of a boolean value. For example:
enum PresentedSheet {
    case sheetOne, sheetTwo, sheetThree
}

If you were to use an value that is optional, then you can have the sheet be presented, whenever the value is NOT nil. For example:
@State presentedSheet: PresentedSheet? = nil

var body: some View {
    Text("Example")
        .sheet(item: $presentedSheet) {
            switch presentedSheet { //Show the view you want }
        }
}

In your case, you'd add the presentedSheet in place of your boolean, on your observable object. If you want additional controls, there is a callback function that can be called onDismiss if you need to know or update something when that sheet is dismissed.
As a final note, when working with sheets, if you're sharing a sheet among different views, be sure to have that sheet presented from the parent most view, or if a particular child view is destroyed it will also automatically dismiss your currently presented sheet. Also, don't overuse this as it can quickly clutter your code or complicate things.

I was able to solve this issue by creating two separate @Published bools in the ObservedObject that each control sheet presentation in their respective View. These values are passed into the View which allow them to be manipulated outside of the View which resolved the deep linking issue I alluded to.
As @xTwisteDx mentioned, the issue stemmed from the binding being flipped to false on the redraw. By assigning a passed in @State property to the sheet binding, the binding was no longer getting flipped. Then all I had to do was create @Published triggers in the ObservedObject so I could turn them on when necessary in the deep linking class.
It's important to note that these two bools can never be on at the same time. So in setting one to true, the other must be set to false
As @workingdogsupportUkraine mentioned, it may not be correct to create a shared instance of the @ObservedObject within itself, but passing the object in to consecutive Views was not an option for me.
So the working code looks like this:
TabView:
struct TabView: View {
    @StateObject private var obsPresentation = ObsPresentation.shared
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    TabView(selection: $obsPresentation.currentTab) {
                            if obsPresentation.conditionOne {
                                HealthView(showSheet: obsPresentation.tiggerSheet1)
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Label("Person 1 Health", systemImage: "heart")
                                    }
                                    .tag(obsPresentation.Tab.health1)
                            }
                            
                            if obsPresentation.conditionTwo {
                                HealthView(showSheet: obsPresentation.triggerSheet2)
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Label("Person 2 Health", systemImage: "heart")
                                    }
                                    .tag(obsPresentation.Tab.health2)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

HealthView:
struct HealthView: View {
    @State var showSheet: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid() {
                    ForEach(...) { _ in
                        Button(action: {
                            showSheet = true
                        }) {
                            ... UI
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

Observed Object:
public class ObsPresentation: ObservableObject {
    public static var shared = ObsPresentation()
    
    public enum Tab {
        case health1, health2
    }
    
    @Published public var currentTab: Tab = .health1 {
        didSet {
            switch tabSelection {
            case .health1:
                ...
            case .health2:
                ...
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
    
// These conditions are manipulated elsewhere
    @Published public var condition1 = true 
    @Published public var condition2 = true
    
    @Published var triggerSheet1 = false
    @Published var triggerSheet2 = false
}


This is not how State is used in SwiftUI.
@State ... should provide an initial value, see State.
Use @Binding var showSheet: Bool in your HealthView and call HealthView(showSheet: $obsPresentation.tiggerSheet1).
Similarly, @StateObject private var obsPresentation = ObsPresentation(), not a singleton shared.
Pass that model to other views if required, as described in the Apple docs Managing model data ios16+.
